# on click drop down menu refreshes on each click

Tags: jquery

I have a site and its mobile version link is as under,

http://www.aamirarif.com/kashif/nitech_mobile/index.html

I have used JQuery onClick drop down menu for this.

when I open this site in a mobile device and click on menu for options, the whole page refreshes, whether it would be only a drop down appearing under the menu?

What is the problem? Any solution to this problem would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no need of creating whole new html page you can use date-role="page" attribute of html5 div tag. soemthing like this

```
<div id="about" data-role="page">

<div data-role = "content">
put your content here
</div>
and then close the page div
</div>
```

and you can call this in jquery function by its id

```
$('#about')
```

in this way page will not refresh ....